# Database Design - Many to Many or One to Many "Deal" System?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have an system that users can do "Deal" with Each other, i'm wondering what kind of relationship i should use.
think of the system like this. 
We have a Database that has two Table, One "Users" and one for "Deals"
every row in 'deal' table is related  to two 'user' row.
so when a deal is created one user is buyer and one user is seller.
how i should design this database?
i mean the logic of tables what should be?
one to one or many to many? and why?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/so7iS.jpg

Comment: Most simple would be to include buyer_user_id and seller_user_id columns in the deal table this is also a valid approach.. Database design questions are always primarily opinion based.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. (Explain the coloured lines.)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Propose a design and ask a specific question about it. Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & 

database design.

Comment: @philipxy please help me to solve problem, otherwise don't spam in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's kinda both 1:many and many:many.

```
CREATE TABLE Deals (
    seller_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- link to `Users`
    buyer_id  SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- link to `Users`
    object_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- link to `Objects`
    price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    etc.,
    PRIMARY KEY(seller_id, buyer_id, object_id),
    INDEX(...)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This allows for multiple object sales between two "users", the same object being sold between other people at other prices, etc, etc.

The "Deal" is an entity, just a "User" is.  But, since a deal involves only one buyer, seller, and object, the relationship is 1:many for deal:person and deal:object.

On the other hand, `Deals` acts like a many:many relationship table in the sense that relates sellers and buyers, sellers an objects, etc.

Some details about the schema:

- You probably want `seller_id` and `buyer_id` to be links to a single `Users` table.  (Unless there is enough difference between buyers and sellers to justify different schemas.)
- The 3 ids in my proposed schema represent the colored lines in your jpg.  That is, you almost finished the schema!
- `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (only 2 bytes) allows 64K ids.  If you don't think that is enough, pick a larger datatype.
- `DECIMAL(8,2)` allows for a price up to 999999.99 dollars, euros, etc.;  change if this does not fit your currency needs.
- The is no need for a `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` in `Deals`.
- Add more `INDEXes` as needed.

(Added...)

If the *same* seller/buyer pair can sell/buy the *same* object_id, then the PK (above) won't work.  (Note: A PK is necessarily "unique".)  To fix this issue, you would need to have

```
deal_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(deal_id),
INDEX(seller_id, buyer_id, object_id),  -- in some order
INDEX(...)
```

When designing a set of tables, I like to focus on what needs to be collected together (eg, the attributes of a "deal").  And make sure the relationships are handled (eg, `seller_id`).  Often things fall into "Entities" (Deals, Users) and "Relationships" (the ids, when 1:many; a separate mapping table when many:many).  In your case, the many:many relationship table is really an Entity in its own right.

I also like to sketch out the `SELECTs` to see whether the tables conveniently support the queries.

Only at the end, will I think about `FOREIGN KEYs`.  Generally, the `INDEXes` map to the FKs.

I rarely use FKs or Triggers -- I want the app code to spell out all the steps of any transaction, including the side-effects that would otherwise be hidden in FKs and Triggers.

Comment: Good answer, thank you, but i have a question, i said i want users have multiple deals with each other, if the seller_id and buyer_id be PRIMARY KEY, so each col can't have repeated values, why you makes the seller_id and buyer_id primary key?

Comment: @HamidAdibzadeh - I made seller+buyer+object the PK.  If each transaction between a seller and buyer involves a different object, then my PK is OK.  If the "object_id" can be the same, then your concern is valid, and a change is needed.  (I'll add to my Answer in a minute.)

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-many relation is not an option here because you need to save additional deal attributes: price, time, object.

So, you could use 2 one-to-many relations between Users and Deals.

You should add:

- SELLER_ID and BUYER_ID fields to Deals table.
- Foreign key referencing from Deals table SELLER_ID field to Users table primary key.
- Foreign key referencing from Deals table BUYER_ID field to Users table primary key.